# Can I define custom character class shorthands?

Tags: java, regex, customization

Java provides some useful character classes like `\d` and `\w`. Can I define my own character classes? For example, it would be useful to be able to define shorthands for character classes like `[A-Za-z_]`.

Comment: That was just an example :) Imagine more complicated character classes that appear repeatedly.

Comment: @Martinho, It also includes `\d`

Comment: Ok. And my comment is a tad wrong. `[\w_]` is not exactly the same as `[A-Za-z_]`. `\w` is letters, digits and underscores. And Unicode aware, I think. Ooops.

Comment: @Martinho, Don't take to heart... :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can I define my own character classes?

No, you can't.

Personally, when I have a (slightly) complicated regex, I break the regex up in smaller sub-regexes and then "glue" them together with a `String.format(...)` like this:

```
public static boolean isValidIP4(String address) {
    String block_0_255 = "(0|[1-9]\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])";
    String regex = String.format(
            "%s(\\.%s){3}", 
            block_0_255, block_0_255
    );
    return address.matches(regex);
}
```

which is far more readable than a single pattern:

```
"(0|[1-9]\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])(\\.(0|[1-9]\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){3}"
```

Note that this is just a quick example: validating IP addresses can probably better be done by a class from the `java.net` package, and if you'd do it like that, the pattern should be placed outside the method and pre-compiled.

Be careful with `%` signs inside your pattern!

Comment: I was about to suggest something this myself. You can keep these regular expression parts in constants somewhere, if you need to reuse them a lot. Have a +1.

Comment: Good answer! I got here looking for ideas. This works almost identically for Python. Feel silly having not thought of it. It doesn't help too much for say, a grep command line, unless you go nuts with something like foo='(0|[1-9]\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])'; grep -E "${foo}(\\.${foo}){3}" bar.txt'. Actually, that's not that awful... would it work in the -exec operator of find? Hmmm.... time to experiment.... Initially, I didn't have the semic

Comment: Initially, I didn't have the semicolon after the definition of "foo", but of course all that does is define "foo" for grep's execution environment, which was not the intension. I was trying to come up with a single command line that didn't pollute the shell session with lots of ad-hoc little re strings. I was hoping to superimpose an environment with an additional foo definition, just to aid in specifying the grep re. Putting the whole thing in a subshell worked, but that probably adds other side effects.  (f='(0|[1-9]\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])'; grep -E "${f}(\\.${f}){3}" bar.txt)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the closest you can get assuming you don't want to write your own complete regex engine is to write a string preprocessor that converts a string containing your shorthand symbols into another string with the symbols expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Yes, because `[]` is already a character class. No, you can not define custom "shortcuts" like `\w`. One reason is, that it were never JAVAs decision. These character classes are standardized somewhere else (POSIX?).

My 2 cent: Regular expressions are complex enough be itself. You shouldn't confuse yourself and others by introducing even more.

Comment: Java imitates Perl `re`s, like pretty much every other `re` library. Perl `re`s are the de-facto standard.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about using these custom shortcuts in regular expressions? If so, the answer is no, unless you write your own regular expression parser (which is something you don't want to do). Those shortcuts are part of a predefined spec that can't be altered.